# I want to make random stopping circles on Panel but my circles don't stop and changing

Tags: java, swing, random

I am new in Java. I want to make simple agario game for my project. But I have a problem. I want to make random stopping circles on Panel but my circles don't stop and changing.

The Problem is I think Timer.

```
class TestPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
TestPanel(){
    Timer t = new Timer(50,this);  
    t.start();
}

Random rnd = new Random();


int r = rnd.nextInt(256);   
int b = rnd.nextInt(256);
int gr = rnd.nextInt(256);

Color randomColor = new Color(r,b,gr);

Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 40, 40);   
double v = 10;  
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g); 

    Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;


    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(ball);    

    int NumOfCircles = 70;  
    int diameter;
    int x, y;


    Graphics2D g3 =(Graphics2D)g;



    for(int count = 0; count < NumOfCircles; count++){
        diameter = rnd.nextInt(10);
        x = rnd.nextInt(600);
        y = rnd.nextInt(620);
        g3.setColor(randomColor);
        g3.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }

    }


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Point p = getMousePosition();
    if(p==null) return;
    double dx = p.x - ball.x - 20;
    double dy = p.y - ball.y - 20;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy >12){
    double a=Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    ball.x += v * Math.cos(a);
    ball.y += v * Math.sin(a);}
    repaint();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your painting code. You can't control when Swing invokes the painting logic. So the painting code should only paint the object based on the properties of the panel and should not modify the properties.

This means:

1. Don't generate random values is a painting method.
2. In the constructor of your class you generate the Circles and assign a default size/location to each Circle. This information is then stored in in an ArrayList. Then in the paintComponent() method you simply iterate through the List and paint each circle.
3. In the `ActionListener` of the `Timer` you then itereate through the ArrayList and update the location of each Circle. Then you invoke repaint() on the panel so all the Circles get repainted.

For example check out: [How to move two circles together in a JFrame from two different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859324/how-to-move-two-circles-together-in-a-jframe-from-two-different-classes/28884575#28884575)